# File upload with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, viewmodel

I want to upload a file. I use MVC3 with razor. I have the following ViewModel:

```
Public Class ImportL2EViewModel
    <Required(AllowEmptyStrings:=False, ErrorMessage:="L2E name required")>
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Property File As HttpPostedFileBase    
End Class
```

In my view I create a form:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Import", "L2ECreationWizard", FormMethod.Post, New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {{"enctype", "multipart/form-data"}})
    @<div class="welcome-box acenter"> 
        <div style="display: block; text-align: left; width: 330px; margin: auto;">
            <div class="property">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Name)
            </div> 
            <div class="property">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.File)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.File, New With {.type = "file"})
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="actionBar">
            <a class="import fright button" href="#">Import</a>
        </div>
    </div>
End Using
```

The resulting html looks like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/L2ECreationWizard/Import" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="welcome-box acenter"> 
        <div style="display: block; text-align: left; width: 330px; margin: auto;">
            <div class="property">
                <label for="Name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="Name" id="Name" data-val-required="L2E name required" data-val="true">
            </div> 
            <div class="property">
                <label for="File">File</label>
                <input type="file" value="" name="File" id="File">
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="actionBar">
            <a href="#" class="import fright button">Import</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I post the form to the following action method:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Import(vm As ImportL2EViewModel) As ActionResult
    ' Nothing yet
End Function
```

After posting I can see `vm.Name` filled out, but `vm.File` is `Nothing`.
`Request.Files.Count` is `0`. What am I doing wrong? I've seen similar questions on SO, but nothing worked for me. I am lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a parameter to your method of `HttpPostedFileBase file` as in:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Import(vm As ImportL2EViewModel, file As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult

Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
    Dim physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName)

    // The files are not actually saved in this demo
    // file.SaveAs(physicalPath)
    ...
End Function
```

And remove the HttpPostedFileBase property from your model. It is part of the Request object so it can't be added to your model.

If you are allowing multiple files to be selected then this is what you need to be able to loop thru each file that was uploaded

```
<HttpPost()>
Function Import(vm As ImportL2EViewModel, attachments As IEnumerable(Of HttpPostedFileBase)) As ActionResult

    For Each file As var In attachments
        Dim fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
        Dim physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName)
        ' The files are not actually saved in this demo
        ' file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
    Next
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said and `file` is still `Nothing`. Also `Request.Files` remains empty...Any idea why that happens? I used fiddler and I do not see any file being transmitted...

Comment: Ok. I know what was happening. I used javascript ajax call to post the form and I forgot about it. You need to do some tricks if you want to post a file with ajax. Lesson learned. I accept your answer, because it assured me that my code is fine and something else must be causing the unexpected behavior.